# Passing Intent without any extra

Tags: android

I am new to android programming, and I still haven't got this intent concept. I viewed android documents in its development website, and it passes intent as

```
public void nothing(View view) //nothing is defined in XML fine as android:onClick="nothing"
//in button
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(this, Learning.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);


    }
```

So, it passes to Learning.class.. But, when I wanted to go another class without passing any extra as in

```
public void nothing(View view) //nothing is defined in XML fine as android:onClick="nothing"
//in button
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(this, Learning.class);
        //  intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);   <--didn't put this one
        startActivity(intent);


    }
```

it shows NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION.

So, what is the problem? Can we not pass intent without any put.Extra?

my Learning activity oncreate looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent=getIntent();
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_learning);
```

Comment: you can. post the stacktrace

Comment: where is the NullPointer? Maybe your code that open that activity, especially `onCreate` method in `Learning.class` tries to get `EXTRA_MESSAGE` or `bundle` and it is `null` because you do not create any before starting it. From programmicaly point of view of course you can create activity without passing extra things in it! But maybe somewhere else you try to get sth from activity extras.

Comment: paste your stack trace of that nullpointer

Comment: If i didn't put EXTRA_MESSAGE while passing the intent, will it automatically ask "where is EXTRA_MESSAGE"?

Answer (score 0):

in Learning class there must be code something like that :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = inetnt.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
// here is the error coz intent is null
```

so just check first if intent is null or no :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if(intent != null){
  String message = inetnt.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
}
```